# Meaning of "..." and "##" in macro definition

Tags: objective-c, syntax, macros

```
#define MyLog(msg...) MyLogWith(__func__,##msg);

MyLog(@"I do not know...");
```

What do `...` and `##` mean in this definition? Is there a special meaning to them being combined with `msg`: `msg..` or `##msg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg...` means to take any amount of arguments.
`,##msg` means paste the arguments, and erase the preceding `,` if the argument count is `0`
`msg` has no special meaning, its just the name for the arguments, e.g.

```
#define MyLog(args...) MyLogWith(__func__,##args);
```

will do the same